# Is this a correct JSON Data Structure?

Tags: php, json

I've converted my php result array to json. Now I want to know is this in the correct json format. My code `echo json_encode($row);`

I have to use it with jquery auto complete plugin...

```
{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Albania","country":"Albania"} 
{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"Algeria","country":"Algeria`"}
{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"Angola","country":"Angola"}
{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"Anguilla","country":"Anguilla"}
{"0":"5","id":"5","1":"Antigua","country":"Antigua"}
{"0":"6","id":"6","1":"Argentina","country":"Argentina"}
{"0":"7","id":"7","1":"Armenia","country":"Armenia"}
{"0":"8","id":"8","1":"Aruba","country":"Aruba"}
{"0":"9","id":"9","1":"Australia","country":"Australia"}
{"0":"10","id":"10","1":"Austria","country":"Austria"}
{"0":"11","id":"11","1":"Azerbaijan","country":"Azerbaijan"}
0":"26","id":"26","1":"Bulgaria","country":"Bulgaria"}
{"0":"27","id":"27","1":"Burkina Faso","country":"Burkina Faso"}
```

Comment: Might be useful: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each object need to wrap in `[]` and need `comma` between them as other said,

And the object which contains **Bulgaria** is broken like this

```
0":"26","id":"26","1":"Bulgaria","country":"Bulgaria"}
```

it should be

```
{"0":"26","id":"26","1":"Bulgaria","country":"Bulgaria"}
```

Correct one would be like

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Albania","country":"Albania"},
{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"Algeria","country":"Algeria`"},
{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"Angola","country":"Angola"},
{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"Anguilla","country":"Anguilla"},
{"0":"5","id":"5","1":"Antigua","country":"Antigua"},
{"0":"6","id":"6","1":"Argentina","country":"Argentina"},
{"0":"7","id":"7","1":"Armenia","country":"Armenia"},
{"0":"8","id":"8","1":"Aruba","country":"Aruba"},
{"0":"9","id":"9","1":"Australia","country":"Australia"},
{"0":"10","id":"10","1":"Austria","country":"Austria"},
{"0":"11","id":"11","1":"Azerbaijan","country":"Azerbaijan"},
{"0":"26","id":"26","1":"Bulgaria","country":"Bulgaria"},
{"0":"27","id":"27","1":"Burkina Faso","country":"Burkina Faso"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

A true json object will be wrapped in { }, while a json array will be wrapped, like Ignacio says in [ ].

Additionally, you can use the options in json_encode to force the formatting. Check your plugin to see if it specifies which format they want it in.

**Edit**

After looking more closely at your object, what you probably want to do is put each row into an array and then json_encode that array.

```
$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Right now, it looks like you're outputting a different json object for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The objects need to be in a top container, e.g. `[{...},{...},...]`.

Comment: It's WRONG. `eval()` won't help.

Comment: echo '[' . json_encode($row) . ']';
However, there seems to be other issues with your code, so you might want to check that out first. (For example, there seems to be an encode error within the json call as it's not rendering correctly on the site, an example of that can be found within your code bit here:
    "country":"Azerbaijan"}0":"26","
See how all of the colors are off after that part? That's a problem.

Comment: @Mark Tomlin: All I see now is blonde, brunette, redhead. xD

Comment: @Alix Axel: Is that an Armageddon reference? Steve Buscemi's character saying then during the psyche eval?

Comment: @Mark Tomlin: It's the MATRIX! =)

Answer (score 0):

Great resource for JSON Validation: http://www.jsonlint.com/